# Flag as non-answer declined, please explain

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I'm new to SO review queues. Yesterday I reviewed a lot of questions, some of them I placed a flag. Two of those flags has been declined. Please help me understand the causes.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529679/a-query-to-show-name-of-the-bus-and-busno-where-source-of-a-bus-is-the-destinat/45523207#45523207)

As I see: Somebody posted an answer that is now accepted. Later a new user posted another answer with code that barely differs from the accepted answer. Since we don't know the RDMS the OP uses, it's not clear that it's correct at all. I flagged this as a non-answer, thinking it's a comment. I know new users can't comment on other people's answers.

My flag was declined - "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

I think that answer should be deleted, at least because it's a duplicate.

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037468/dude-where-is-my-django-installation/45523475#45523475)

Same story here. The answer is just an addition to olafure's answer.

Comment: I like it when new users trying to understand what they did wrong in order to improve. You flag posts as NAA (Not an answer) when they don't follow these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). You DO NOT flag posts for moderator attention if they can be handled by the rest of the community

Comment: I think "commentary on the question or other answers" prevails on these answers.  How can the community handle these questions? Simply through down votes?

Comment: No, when you get to 3k reputation you can cast close/reopen votes on flagged questions ([read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)) and when you get to 10K you can also cast [delete votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) on questions, and when you hit 20K reputation you become a _trusted user_ which mean that you get to also case a votes to [delete answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)

Comment: *I think that answer should be deleted, at least because it's a duplicate*, No, NAA flags aren't used to indicate that. See [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). (If the answer is a 100% copy of the other answer, except for the formatting, then use a custom flag and indicate the same. We can then delete it).

Comment: Thank you, there is a nice explanation in that question's accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your Not an Answer flags for things like this:

- I've been having the same problem? Can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work, too? *code block*
- Thanks, that worked for me!
- What database are you using? I don't quite understand the details of your question?

Basically, the first one should be it's own question and the last two should have been comments.

Posts that duplicate an answer already given should be downvoted and custom flagged explaining that another user already gave that answer. Don't do this for people who post a very similar answer within moments of each other, though. Save this for those Late Answer reviews where two years after an answer was accepted someone comes by and posts part of that same answer without adding anything significantly different to justify it being unique.

Remember that crummy answers are still answers. I personally tend to use my downvotes on answers like I described above or on answers where I am knowledgeable in the technology described and I spot something factually wrong with it. In those cases I also leave a comment about why I downvoted their answer so they have an opportunity to fix it. If a post is edited, you have the opportunity to retract your vote.

Answer (score 6):

While answers might be wrong, or duplicate, they are *still answers*.

Instead of flagging them as "not an answer", you should downvote incorrect answers and try to improve where you can.